# Error while deploying soap web service to WebLogic 12c

Tags: java, eclipse, cxf, weblogic12c

I am trying to create soap web service in Eclipse Oxygen using apache cxf 3.1.9 and deploy it to WebLogic 12.2.1 but got an error:

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.abdera.writer.Writer
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.abdera.writer.Writer    
  at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:981)
  at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:942)
  at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:83)
  at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:564)
  at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:500)
  at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:464)
  at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:441)
  at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:53)
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$2.run(IntrospectionModeller.java:253)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.getAllDeclaredMethods(IntrospectionModeller.java:247)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.checkForNonPublicMethodIssues(IntrospectionModeller.java:172)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.doCreateResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:119)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.access$000(IntrospectionModeller.java:80)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:112)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:109)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.createResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:109)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Resource.from(Resource.java:797)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:465)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:362)
  at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:343)
...
```

or the same error but it can't find org.apache.abdera.model.Element.

When I used WebLogic 12.1.3 there were not any problems.

How can I fix this error? And what is purpose of these classes? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

After adding Apache Abdera in classpath, I got new error:

```
Caused by: weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.lang.Class<?>[] from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class<?>[]) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class[])', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.lang.Class<?>[] from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class<?>[]) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class[])', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader<T> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyReader.setDelegatingReader(javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader<T>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyReader.setDelegatingReader(javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.List<javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader<T>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyReader.setDelegatingReaders(java.util.List<javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader<T>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyReader.setDelegatingReaders(java.util.List)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type T from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(T) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(java.lang.Object)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type T from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(T) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(java.lang.Object)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter<T> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyWriter.setDelegatingWriter(javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter<T>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyWriter.setDelegatingWriter(javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.List<javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter<T>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyWriter.setDelegatingWriters(java.util.List<javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter<T>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyWriter.setDelegatingWriters(java.util.List)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type T from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(T) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(java.lang.Object)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementWriter<?, ?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomWriters(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementWriter<?, ?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomWriters(java.util.Map)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementReader<?, ?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomReaders(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementReader<?, ?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomReaders(java.util.Map)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AbstractAtomElementBuilder<?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomBuilders(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AbstractAtomElementBuilder<?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomBuilders(java.util.Map)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementWriter<?, ?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomClassWriters(java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementWriter<?, ?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomClassWriters(java.util.Map)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementReader<?, ?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomClassReaders(java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementReader<?, ?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomClassReaders(java.util.Map)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AbstractAtomElementBuilder<?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomClassBuilders(java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AbstractAtomElementBuilder<?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomClassBuilders(java.util.Map)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.lang.Class<?>[] from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class<?>[]) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class[])', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<? extends java.lang.Enum<?>, java.lang.String> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.RequestDispatcherProvider.setEnumResources(java.util.Map<? extends java.lang.Enum<?>, java.lang.String>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.RequestDispatcherProvider.setEnumResources(java.util.Map)', 
[WARNING] The (sub)resource method removeToken in org.apache.cxf.sts.rest.RESTSecurityTokenService contains empty path annotation.; source='public abstract javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.sts.rest.RESTSecurityTokenService.removeToken(org.apache.cxf.ws.security.sts.provider.model.RequestSecurityTokenType)', 
[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.RedirectionBasedGrantService.authorize() and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth.services.AuthorizationRequestService.authorize() at matching regular expression /authorize. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@7afda511', 
[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.RedirectionBasedGrantService.authorize() and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.AuthorizationService.authorize(java.lang.String) at matching regular expression /authorize. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@7afda511', 
[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth.services.AuthorizationRequestService.authorize() and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.AuthorizationService.authorize(java.lang.String) at matching regular expression /authorize. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@7afda511', 
[HINT] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and output mime-types as defined by @Produces annotation at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.RedirectionBasedGrantService.authorizeDecision() and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth.services.AuthorizationRequestService.authorizeDecision() at matching path pattern /decision.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@3a01f754', 
[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.RedirectionBasedGrantService.authorizeDecision() and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.AuthorizationService.authorizeDecision(java.lang.String) at matching regular expression /decision. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@3a01f754', 
[HINT] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method POST and input mime-types as defined by "@Consumes" annotation at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.RedirectionBasedGrantService.authorizeDecisionForm(javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap) and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth.services.AuthorizationRequestService.authorizeDecisionForm() at matching path pattern /decision. This could cause an error for conflicting output types!; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@3a01f754', 
[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method POST and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.RedirectionBasedGrantService.authorizeDecisionForm(javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap) and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.AuthorizationService.authorizeDecisionForm(javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap) at matching regular expression /decision. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@3a01f754', 
[HINT] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and output mime-types as defined by @Produces annotation at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth.services.AuthorizationRequestService.authorizeDecision() and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.AuthorizationService.authorizeDecision(java.lang.String) at matching path pattern /decision.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@3a01f754', 
[HINT] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method POST and output mime-types as defined by @Produces annotation at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth.services.AuthorizationRequestService.authorizeDecisionForm() and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.AuthorizationService.authorizeDecisionForm(javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap) at matching path pattern /decision.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@3a01f754']:org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException:Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.lang.Class<?>[] from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class<?>[]) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class[])', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.lang.Class<?>[] from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class<?>[]) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class[])', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader<T> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyReader.setDelegatingReader(javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader<T>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyReader.setDelegatingReader(javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.List<javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader<T>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyReader.setDelegatingReaders(java.util.List<javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader<T>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyReader.setDelegatingReaders(java.util.List)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type T from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(T) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(java.lang.Object)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type T from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(T) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(java.lang.Object)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter<T> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyWriter.setDelegatingWriter(javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter<T>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyWriter.setDelegatingWriter(javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.List<javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter<T>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyWriter.setDelegatingWriters(java.util.List<javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter<T>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyWriter.setDelegatingWriters(java.util.List)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type T from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(T) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(java.lang.Object)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementWriter<?, ?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomWriters(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementWriter<?, ?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomWriters(java.util.Map)', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementReader<?, ?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomReaders(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementReader<?, ?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomReaders(java.util.Map)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AbstractAtomElementBuilder<?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomBuilders(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AbstractAtomElementBuilder<?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomBuilders(java.util.Map)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementWriter<?, ?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomClassWriters(java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementWriter<?, ?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomClassWriters(java.util.Map)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementReader<?, ?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomClassReaders(java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementReader<?, ?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomClassReaders(java.util.Map)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AbstractAtomElementBuilder<?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomClassBuilders(java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AbstractAtomElementBuilder<?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomClassBuilders(java.util.Map)', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.lang.Class<?>[] from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class<?>[]) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class[])', 
[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<? extends java.lang.Enum<?>, java.lang.String> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.RequestDispatcherProvider.setEnumResources(java.util.Map<? extends java.lang.Enum<?>, java.lang.String>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.RequestDispatcherProvider.setEnumResources(java.util.Map)', 
[WARNING] The (sub)resource method removeToken in org.apache.cxf.sts.rest.RESTSecurityTokenService contains empty path annotation.; source='public abstract javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.sts.rest.RESTSecurityTokenService.removeToken(org.apache.cxf.ws.security.sts.provider.model.RequestSecurityTokenType)', [FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.RedirectionBasedGrantService.authorize() and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth.services.AuthorizationRequestService.authorize() at matching regular expression /authorize. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@7afda511', 
[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.RedirectionBasedGrantService.authorize() and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.AuthorizationService.authorize(java.lang.String) at matching regular expression /authorize. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@7afda511', 
[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth.services.AuthorizationRequestService.authorize() and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.AuthorizationService.authorize(java.lang.String) at matching regular expression /authorize. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@7afda511', 
[HINT] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and output mime-types as defined by @Produces annotation at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.RedirectionBasedGrantService.authorizeDecision() and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth.services.AuthorizationRequestService.authorizeDecision() at matching path pattern /decision.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@3a01f754', 
[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.RedirectionBasedGrantService.authorizeDecision() and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.AuthorizationService.authorizeDecision(java.lang.String) at matching regular expression /decision. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@3a01f754', 
[HINT] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method POST and input mime-types as defined by "@Consumes" annotation at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.RedirectionBasedGrantService.authorizeDecisionForm(javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap) and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth.services.AuthorizationRequestService.authorizeDecisionForm() at matching path pattern /decision. This could cause an error for conflicting output types!; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@3a01f754', 
[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method POST and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.RedirectionBasedGrantService.authorizeDecisionForm(javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap) and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.AuthorizationService.authorizeDecisionForm(javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap) at matching regular expression /decision. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@3a01f754', [HINT] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and output mime-types as defined by @Produces annotation at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth.services.AuthorizationRequestService.authorizeDecision() and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.AuthorizationService.authorizeDecision(java.lang.String) at matching path pattern /decision.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@3a01f754', 
[HINT] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method POST and output mime-types as defined by @Produces annotation at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth.services.AuthorizationRequestService.authorizeDecisionForm() and public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.services.AuthorizationService.authorizeDecisionForm(javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap) at matching path pattern /decision.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@3a01f754']
...
```

Comment: Check your classpath. You have a dependency with the Apache Abdera library which should be in your application's classpath or in your server's classpath

Comment: @Emmanuel Collin, but weblogic 12.1.3 didn't require this library, why should i use it?

Comment: I added Apache Abdera dependency in classpath, but then I get other error message: weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization... But I don't use Jersey. What's problem?

Comment: it is required by you application, maybe by CXF or by another framework or component embedded in your application.
WLS does not require this library to run.

Post the log about the jersey erorr

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin I updated my question. Log has too much symbols than is why I put there a big part of it.

Comment: @NickSheinov did you manage to fix the second error ? Could you please let me know the fix ?

Answer (score 0):

Had exact same issue **ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.abdera.writer.Writer**
with org.apache.cxf:cxf-bundle:jar:**2.7.11** and javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:**2.0-m10** deploying to wls 12.2.1.4.0 when upgrading from 10.3.6.0
Solution was to make sure all jersey libs were excluded and included this in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.abdera</groupId>
    <artifactId>abdera-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Plus in weblogic.xml:

```
<library-ref>
   <library-name>jax-rs</library-name>
   <specification-version>2.0</specification-version>
   <exact-match>false</exact-match>
</library-ref>    
<container-descriptor>      
  <prefer-application-packages> 
    <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name> 
    <package-name>org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.*</package-name> 
    <package-name>javax.ws.*</package-name> 
    <package-name>javax.jws.*</package-name> 
  </prefer-application-packages> 
</container-descriptor>
```

And finally install jax-rs 2.0 shared lib into weblogic prior to the deployment, like it says [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/RESTF/use-jersey20-ri.htm#RESTF290), or you will get this:

> weblogic.application.ModuleException: Error: Unresolved Webapp Library
> references for ..., defined in weblogic.xml [Extension-Name: jax-rs,
> Specification-Version: 2, exact-match: false]